# Is it okay to ask "has * been done?" questions?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709071/has-anyone-ever-tried-to-jit-compile-a-macro-language) question and it was downvoted and close-voted. I thought it was a legitimate question (the idea of JITing TeX was brought up on one website) and am trying to understand why it was so bad.

Did I ask the question in a poor way, or are "has * been done?" questions off-topic for SO?

Comment: Closely related questions: *"Is it possible?"*, *"Any idea?"*, and *"Anyone else have this problem?"*  They are all bad questions because answering them doesn't solve any problem or provide any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I ask the question in a poor way, or are "has * been done?" questions off-topic for SO?

Both.  Read the comments to your question.

"Has * been done" is a yes or no question, and nobody can answer "no" with confidence.  Thus, it is not answerable.

As for whether you can "JIT" a particular language, of course you can -- if you can write a compiler.

Comment: I thought I'd made that very clear in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709071/has-anyone-ever-tried-to-jit-compile-a-macro-language#comment38320915_24709071) to that question (and a second time in a follow-up comment after a terrible edit), and so had the others that voted to close. Apparently there are additional opinions needed to clarify. Hopefully, your effort will succeed. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite You were quite clear in your comments.  I don't know why a post to Meta is appropriate for this, unless the OP's goal is to get his question closed more quickly.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg it is so that I can know not to ask questions in the category in the future - the second part of my meta question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: *"As for whether you can "JIT" a particular language, of course you can -- if you can write a compiler."* => And you can write a compiler for any language you can interpret, though as the saying goes: "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is."